# Cannot connect to the mySQL database from cloud foundry app

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry

I can connect to the mySQL db using MAMP and install directus as expected locally.  When trying to install directus using a local apache server from Terminal I have to do a manual installation.  When I try to install directus from my deployed app on cloud foundry, I cannot reach the mySQL db.  I click the save button on the database connection page and the spin wheel appears for a few seconds but nothing happens.  I get a 500 error.  When I create the api.php file in cloud foundry, I get the message can't connect to database on the login page. mod_rewrite is enabled as well as the appropriate extensions.  Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

edit: here is the JSON response I am getting:

> code:     11   message:   Failed to connect to the database Connect Error:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>   class:    Directus\Database\Exception\ConnectionFailedException   file:
>   directus/src/core/Directus/Application/CoreServicesProvider.php
>   line: 702

Comment: sounds like probably your connection details are wrong or the database is not running

Comment: I am able to connect locally using the exact same api.php file. Something is different between my local environment and my cloud setup.  I cannot pinpoint what is causing the connection issue.

Comment: yes, like I said, probably the connection details are not right in the other environment. Check where the database is actually located in that environment, and whether it's running

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the IP address instead of the p-mysql... string to connect to the DB. It was a PCF problem and not directus. Thanks for the support @ADyson